# Creating an MS Word add-in: Is there any way to get rid of grammar/spelling suggestions in text input fields?

Tags: ms-word, office-js, word-addins

Spelling and grammar aren't important for my inputs since they're search boxes for concatenated words that will trigger the spell/grammar check 90% of the time. I'm trying to get rid of them to give the add-in a cleaner look.

In case what I'm talking about isn't super clear, here's a screenshot of what I mean:[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which OS is this? And this is in a task pane, right?

Comment: I don't visually recognize that type of text input field, but if you can assign a unique Word Style to it, then you could set that style with a "Do Not Spellcheck" property.